# How to block a QML item from getting panned out or its parent's boundaries

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I have the following code which allows panning of an image on an application window

**Code:**

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

ApplicationWindow {
    id: app
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Test panning an Image")

    width: 700
    height: 700

    Image {
        id: my_image_item
        source: "http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/images/declarative-qtlogo.png"
        MouseArea{
            anchors.fill: parent
            drag.target: my_image_item
            drag.axis: Drag.XAndYAxis
        }
    }
}
```

**Objective:**
I want to block the image from getting dragged/panned outside its parent.

Basically **I do not want to allow** `my_image_item` to be moved out to a position where :

- `my_image_item`'s right edge is placed leftwards of its parent's left edge,
- `my_image_item`'s left edge is placed rightwards of its parent's right edge
- `my_image_item`'s top edge is placed downwards of its parent's bottom edge
- `my_image_item`'s bottom edge is placed upwards of its parent's top edge

**Primary Question:**
How can I limit the movement of `my_image_item` only within the edges of its parent while user is dragging `my_image_item`?

**Secondary question:** (*if answered then great*):
The item that limits `my_image_item`'s movement needs to be strictly its parent? Or it could be another item which is not its parent as well ? (*at least one that shares a common QML parent*)

Comment: did you try with `onDragFinished()`

Comment: how will `onDragFinished` help ?

Comment: @Game_Of_Threads it won't help. What would help is overcoming laziness and applying some basic, 3rd grade math to set the drag limits to map to whatever area you want to constrain the drag to. A hint - you must also take into account the dragged item dimensions and the point of origin of the drag relative to the dragged item.

Comment: @dtech I almost figured this out in the answer I posted to my question below. But deleted that answer because it was just a little 10% away from the requirement I set in the question. But anyways, I figured out that math myself. I will update my answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you try to use drag.maximumX/drag.minimumX

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-mousearea.html#drag.minimumX-prop

```
Image {
        id: my_image_item
        source: "http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/images/declarative-qtlogo.png"
        MouseArea{
            anchors.fill: parent
            drag.target: my_image_item
            drag.axis: Drag.XAndYAxis
            drag.minimumX: my_image_item.x
            drag.maximumX: my_image_item.right // my_image_item.x + width ???
            drag.minimumY: my_image_item.y
            drag.maximumY: my_image_item.bottom // my_image_item.y + height ???
        }
    }
```

Comment: ok. this does not work exactly in the way I need. but I can make it work using some math around the 4 edges. accepting this answer. thanks

Answer (score 3):

I got the answer to my question from [Qt docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-mousearea.html#drag-prop) itself.

Adding the following additionally to `MouseArea`'s drag properties **limits** its movement to within its parent's boundaries.

**Solution:**

```
drag.minimumX: 0
drag.maximumX: app.width - my_image_item.width
drag.minimumY: 0
drag.maximumY: app.height - my_image_item.height
```

Gives me exactly the behaviour I wanted to simulate in the 4 bullet points listed in the question.

Following is how the final test app looks like:

**Full code:**

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

ApplicationWindow {
    id: app
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Test panning an Image")

    width: 700
    height: 700

    Image {
        id: my_image_item
        source: "http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/images/declarative-qtlogo.png"
        MouseArea{
            anchors.fill: parent
            drag.target: my_image_item
            drag.axis: Drag.XAndYAxis

            drag.minimumX: 0
            drag.maximumX: app.width - my_image_item.width
            drag.minimumY: 0
            drag.maximumY: app.height - my_image_item.height
        }
    }
}
```

I am still in process of figuring out the answer to my additional secondary question

Answer (score 1):

the solution was posted by the author himself, but I thought I would try to explain it a little bit.

`drag.minimum` and `drag.maximum` take a number as a value, that is why accepted answer (that uses parent anchors) will not work. Limiting movement to parent is then indeed like this:

```
drag.minimumY: 0
drag.minimumX: 0
drag.maximumY: parent.height
drag.maximumX: parent.width
```

But this counts with the fact the dragged element is placed on `x: 0; y: 0` like it is by default. If you place is somewhere else, replace the zeroes by its **initial** coordinates.

---

As for the secondary question - you see you are limiting the **drag amount** itself, it is not strictly bound to any single component. You are saying that the component can be dragged *this much* in *these directions*.

If you are going to limit dragging to completely unrelated component, be careful about the minimum, maximum drag amounts and about initial placement of your dragged element.